# In browser's native mode , onchange event is sending incorrect parameter value to the function

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xslt

In xsl input tag 
Onchange ="gridEntryChange(event) ;" is used and it works fine in browsers standard mode. When I alert(event) it shows [object] but in native mode when I alert(event) it shows [object Event] .

Hence in native mode it sends some incorrect object in the function and the functions flow gets screwed up. I am not sure how to solve this issue in native mode , so that correct object is passed to the function and the functions flow doesn't get messed up.

Even when I alert (window.event) in native mode it shows [object Event] but in standard mode it shows [object]

Anyone knows why this is getting incorrect in native mode

Comment: try ```alert(JSON.stringify(event))```

Comment: and how is it different? Why are you using alert to debug? What does xslt and xml have to do with this?

Comment: The code is like this

Comment: <xsl:when test="$isCellEffective != '0'"> <input title= "{$Interval} onchange = " gridEntryChange(event);" and than some other events like onkeypress etc

Comment: @eugene Jason will not work in my case this is plain old JavaScript with blend of XML xslt

Comment: I found the solution in the function keycode was used which was coming as undefined. In native mode keycode cannot be used with onchange event